# What's this window called, and how do I get rid of it

Tags: 16.04, unity

Running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and I suddenly have a new system window at the bottom of my desktop.  It has icons for running programs, and the date and time.

1. What is it called?
2. How can I get rid of it?

See image:

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks like `tint2` dock. Potentially you got it as dependency when installing an app recently.

Close it with  `pkill tint2` or `pkill -f tint2` command. If that starts automatically at login, just open Startup Applications menu and remove it from the list.